# Hide Titlebar but not frameless

Tags: javascript, python, pywebview

I want to create a window with pywebview that hides the titlebar (so I can style my own) but still behaves like a normal window would.

When setting `frameless=True` the titlebar is hidden, but the window no longer behaves as it should e.g. no minimization animation, docking it nor the Windows 11 border-radius.